# Which Canadian airport will my work permit be processed at?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, working-holiday

I am going to Canada on a working holiday visa (IEC).

I am flying from Ireland to Vancouver and then to Edmonton.

I must present my documents to immigration officers at the Port of Entry in order to get a work permit issued.

Which airport should this be processed at, Vancouver (where I have a short stopover) or Edmonton (my destination)?

Answer (score 5):

You will pass through Canadian Immigration in Vancouver, where they will process your application for a work permit. Your flight from Vancouver to Edmonton will be a domestic flight with no formalities in Edmonton.

Comment: Thank you, it went exactly as you said. Note for fellow travellers: queueing at Immigration desk took 2 hours, I was very lucky to make my connecting flight.